# is /sbin/init an executable?

Tags: linux, initrd

```
# Mount the root filesystem.
1 .mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/root
# Boot the real thing.
2 .exec switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init
```

This is a piece of code from /init file of initramfs as mentioned in [gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Init).
here the rootfs mounted to /mnt/root
and later switch_root is performed with /mnt/root as newroot and /sbin/init as destination.

After line 1 is executed the contents of /dev/sda1 is mounted at /mnt/root.
i tried,

`sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda1 /mnt/temp` and got this message,

**mount: /mnt/temp: /dev/sda1 already mounted on /boot/efi.**

so I tried, `cd /boot/efi` and it stated

**cd: command not found**

so I tried `./efi` in the /boot dir but now i got this msg,

**bash: ./efi: Is a directory**

then i tried to view the contents of /sbin/init as:

`cd /sbin/init` but now it says,

**bash: cd: /sbin/init: Not a directory**.

i am confused .how come /dev/sda1 and /mnt/root are directories but all of a sudden /sbin/init is an executable ? shouldn't that be a directory as well ?

Comment: Why should it be a directory just because some of the others are?

Comment: Also, getting `cd: command not found` from a shell sounds curious, especially since later the `cd` worked. I'd guess you did something odd when entering that command.

Comment: `/sbin/init` isn't the destination, it's the program to execute as the new `init`.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, ```switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init``` switch_root here should move the contents of ```/mnt/root ``` to ```/sbin/init``` and make ```/sbin/init``` as the new root filesystem. if the contents are moved then whatever is present in /mnt/root will be present in /sbin/init right ? so if /mnt/root is a directory then /sbin/init must also be a directory right ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because that's not what `switch_root` does at *all*. If you'll look at the manpage, it explicitly says what it does.

Comment: thanks Shadur, @Stewart for explaining it in simple terms .understood clearly !

Answer (score 2):

The confusion here arises because you've misunderstood what `switch_root` does.

From the manpage:

```
NAME
       switch_root - switch to another filesystem as the root of the mount tree

SYNOPSIS
       switch_root [-hV]

       switch_root newroot init [arg...]

DESCRIPTION
       switch_root  moves  already  mounted  /proc,  /dev,  
       /sys  and  /run to newroot and makes newroot the new root
       filesystem and starts init process.

       WARNING: switch_root removes recursively all 
       files and directories on the current root filesystem.
```

What this means, in layman's terms, is that the **directory** specified as the first argument (in your case, `/mnt/root` becomes the new root filesystem (it becomes `/`), the various virtual filesystem trees are mounted, and the **program** specified as the second argument is executed as the new `init`.

More importantly, it looks like those instructions are wrong and don't apply to whatever setup you have, because in your case `/dev/sda1` is where your EFI filesystem is mounted.

I *strongly* recommend you not try to execute this until you know what you're doing and why.

Answer (score 2):

The [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/switch_root.8.html) says:

> ```
> SWITCH_ROOT(8)                               System Administration                                                   > SWITCH_ROOT(8)
>
> NAME
>       switch_root - switch to another filesystem as the root of the
>       mount tree
>
> SYNOPSIS
>       switch_root newroot init [arg...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>       switch_root moves already mounted /proc, /dev, /sys and /run
>       to newroot and makes newroot the new root filesystem and
>       starts init process.
> ```

So when you run `switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init`, you are using making `/mnt/root/` as `/`, copying a few system directories, and then executing `/sbin/init`.

On my debian system `/sbin/init` is a symbolic link:

```
$ ls -la /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Aug 17 22:28 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

It's linked to `/lib/systemd/systemd` which is an executable:

```
$ ls -la /lib/systemd/systemd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1649088 Aug 17 22:28 /lib/systemd/systemd
```